# PSQL update query with json usuing shell script

Tags: shell, psql

I want to run the below using shell script.

```
psql -U postgres -d webstore -c "update business set subscription='{"nextSubscriptionPlan": null, "currentPlanEndDateTime": 1893456000000, "nextPlanSubscriptionId": null, "currentSubscriptionPlan": "Demo", "currentPlanSubscriptionId": null, "nextPlanActivationDateTime": null, "currentPlanActivatedDateTime": 1587050358298}' where businessid='buz_0000001'"
```

But I'm getting below response.

```
FATAL:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: update business set subscription='{nextSubscriptionPl...
                                                ^
DETAIL:  Token "nextSubscriptionPlan" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {nextSubscriptionPlan...
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
connection to server was lost
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "Why is running this SQL statement causing an error?", then I believe that you will need to escape some of the double quotes in your terminal command:

```
psql -U postgres -d webstore -c "update business set subscription='{\"nextSubscriptionPlan\": null, \"currentPlanEndDateTime\": 1893456000000, \"nextPlanSubscriptionId\": null, \"currentSubscriptionPlan\": \"Demo\", \"currentPlanSubscriptionId\": null, \"nextPlanActivationDateTime\": null, \"currentPlanActivatedDateTime\": 1587050358298}' where businessid='buz_0000001'"
```